# stuck as to why django is not finding this url?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

my url is like this...

```
/eng/blog/site-news/
```

the error that comes up looks like this...

```
^admin/
^(?P<page_lang>\w+)/blog/
^(?P<page_lang>\w+)/blog/
^(?P<page_lang>\w+)/blog/
^$
^(?P<category>\w+)/$
^(?P<category>\w+)/post/(?P<post_title>\w+)/$
```

I've done this before and never ran into this problem, it has to be something small that I am not seeing

urls.py #1

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^(?P<page_lang>\w+)/blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^comments/', include('django_comments.urls')),
url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
```

urls.py #2

```
url(r'^$', 'blog.views.main_page'),
url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)/$', 'blog.views.category_page'),
url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)/post/(?P<post_title>\w+)/$', 'blog.views.post_page'),
```

Comment: Do you have multiple `urls.py` files? Would you mind posting the `urls.py` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\w` matches digits, alphabets, and `_`; you need to include `-`:

```
^(?P<category>\w+)/post/(?P<post_title>[-\w]+)/$
```

Answer (score 1):

or just anything except `/`

```
^(?P<category>\w+)/post/(?P<post_title>[^/]*)/$
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `/` in Python regular expression.